# Importing Keyboard from Pynput Causes exe to Instantly Close

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, pynput, python-3.9

EDIT: turns out the issue was program crashing, nothing to do with input being ignored

So I wanted to use keyboard from pynput but when I do that any code after that point can't stop the application from exiting. I know that a simple way to stop an application from exiting is to start an input prompt, but this does not work after I import keyboard.

Also this problem only happens after building an exe using pyinstaller and running the application. Everything works fine if I just double click the .py file itself but I want the exe to actually run properly.

Here is a very short code snippet to show the exact difference between what works and what doesn't

```
input("This input actually works in an EXE")
from pynput import keyboard
input("This input instantly closes in an EXE preventing me from actually using anything from keyboard")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error was because of it not running properly as exe due to the current version of pynput. Solution was to uninstall pynput and install an older version (1.6.8) https://pypi.org/project/pynput/1.6.8/